# QT5 ASSERT failure in QBitArray::QBitArray, "Size must be greater than or equal to 0."

Tags: c++, qt

Hey When running my program, I sometimes get an error like this:
ASSERT failure in QBitArray::QBitArray, "Size must be greater than or equal to 0."
I import a database file into the program,and then display the drawing waveform in the interface. When I repeatedly import the file,this error message pops up.
My program environment is windows7 VS+Qt5.6.  I have used QByteArray to parse data, but have never used the QBitArray class in my solution.  Since it is not required, and "abort", "retry", or "ignore" cannot locate the error, the call stack is all Qt plug-ins.  I don't know how to locate the error.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRZBU.png)

Comment: can you please show us how are you trying to read the array... the msg is suggesting, you are using a variable with negative values...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.